# Не работает proxy с аутентификацией Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, request

```
  var request = require('request');
    var proxyUrl = "http://" + 'EvjhdznB' + ":" + 'ouQEtyk7' + "@" + '5.177.222.233' + ":" + '8080';

var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({
      'proxy': proxyUrl
    });

    proxiedRequest.get("http://whoer.net", function (err, resp, body) {
      console.log(err)
      //console.log(resp)
    console.log(body)
    })
```

Не понимаю, почему с некоторыми сайтами типа google.com прокси работает, а с русскими сайтами типа 2ip, vk это не работает и выдает ошибку

```
`502 Bad Gateway</h2><h3>Host Not Found or connection failed<`
```

есть еще порт socks 11319
модуль request с ним вообще не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в двух протоколах IPv6 и IPv4, данный прокси, который я использую , работает на протоколе ipv6, оказывается добрая половина сайтов в рунете не поддерживает данный протокол и в большинстве своем работают на протоколе ipv4